# Circular reference in Javascript object?

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me understand why below code result in circular reference?

```
var john = {};
var bob = {};
john.friend = bob;
bob.friend = john;
john = null;
console.log(bob.friend); //{ friend: { friend: [Circular] } }
```

Comment: Bob's friend is John and John's friend is Bob and Bob's friend is John and John's friend is Bob and ...

Comment: Sounds like the actual question is rather, “explain to me what a circular reference _is_” ..?

Answer (score 4):

```
bob.friend === john
bob.friend.friend === bob
bob.friend.friend.friend === john
bob.friend.friend.friend.friend === bob
bob.friend.friend.friend.friend.friend === john
```

etc

It goes on and on in a never ending circle where each object refers back to the next one in the circle until it gets back to the start (which is really quickly as this circle only has two members)

---

> ```
> john = null;
> ```

Technically, none of the objects in the first section of code in this answer are a match for `john` since you `null`ed that variable. They are a match for the value that `john` held *before* the `null` assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It is circular because both objects are referencing each other with a property, so it will never end...

On the other hand if you set `john = null`, the variable `john` will no longer reference your object, but that object will still be working because the reference of john will be saved in memory,

```js
var john = {name:'john'};
var bob = {name:'bob'};
john.friend = bob;
bob.friend = john;
john = null;
console.log(john);
console.log(bob.friend);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of object reference because it can be avoided by creating a new references for the two object (by using `Object.assign` or `spread`)

```js
var john = {};
var bob = {};
john.friend = {...bob};
bob.friend = {...john};
console.log(bob.friend);
```

```js
var john = {};
var bob = {};
john.friend = Object.assign({}, bob);
bob.friend = Object.assign({}, john);
console.log(bob.friend);
```